# ZF2 getServiceLocator in ControllerPlugin class

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to get service locator/entity manager in plugin class, How can I get that.

In my controller I am getting it like this.

```
public function getEntityManager()
{
    if(null === $this->em){
        $this->em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
    }
    return $this->em;
}

public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}
```

but in plugin class I am getting error  on $this->getServiceLocator() line. because this is not available in plugin class.

How can I do the same so that I can fetch some records and insert few in database in plugin.

I do have MvcEvent $e object in my plugin class, I can make use of this to get entity manager?

I have used [this plugin](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/zend-framework-2-controllerpluginmanager-append-controller-pluginto-all-controller/) to create my plugin

Any guide will be appriciated.

update:

```
namespace Auth\Controller\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;
use Zend\EventManager\EventInterface as Event;
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Auth\Entity\User;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
class AclPlugin extends AbstractPlugin
{

    /*
    * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
    */
    protected $em;

    public function checkAcl($e)
    {

        $auth = new AuthenticationService();
        if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
            $storage = $auth->getStorage()->read();            
            if (!empty($storage->role))
                $role = strtolower ( $storage->role );            
            else 
                $role = "guest";            
        } else {
            $role = "guest";            
        }
        $app = $e->getParam('application');
        $acl          = new \Auth\Acl\AclRules(); 

        $matches      = $e->getRouteMatch();
        $controller   = $matches->getParam('controller');
        $action       = $matches->getParam('action', 'index');

        $resource = strtolower( $controller );
        $permission = strtolower( $action );

        if (!$acl->hasResource($resource)) {
            throw new \Exception('Resource ' . $resource . ' not defined');
        }

        if ($acl->isAllowed($role, $resource, $permission)) {

            $query = $this->getEntityManager($e)->createQuery('SELECT u FROM Auth\Entity\User u');
            $resultIdentities = $query->execute();

            var_dump($resultIdentities);
            exit();


            return;

        } else {
            $matches->setParam('controller', 'Auth\Controller\User'); // redirect
            $matches->setParam('action', 'accessdenied');    

            return;
        }


    }


    public function getEntityManager($e) {

        var_dump($this->getController()); // returns null
        exit();
        if (null === $this->em) {
            $this->em = $this->getController()->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');

        }
        return $this->em;
    }

    public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

}
```

I am calling above class in module.php

```
    public function onBootstrap(Event $e) 
    {

        $application = $e->getApplication();        
        $services    = $application->getServiceManager();        

        $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $eventManager->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'loadConfiguration'),101);

    }

public function loadConfiguration(MvcEvent $e)
    {

        $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()
                  ->get('ControllerPluginManager')->get('AclPlugin')
                  ->checkAcl($e); //pass to the plugin...      

    }
```

I am registering this plugin in module.config.php

```
return array(  
 'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Auth\Controller\User' => 'Auth\Controller\UserController',
        ),
    ), 

    'controller_plugins' => array(
      'invokables' => array(
          'AclPlugin' => 'Auth\Controller\Plugin\AclPlugin',
      ),  
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What do you mean with "Plugin Class"? In case you're talking abount controller plugins, you can access it using (from the controller plugin's scope): `$this->getController()->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');`.

For other classes, I usually create a factory that injects the ServiceManager instance automatically. For example, in the Module class:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'myServiceClass' => function(ServiceManager $sm) {
                $instance = new Class();
                $instance->setServiceManager($sm);
                // Do some other configuration

                return $instance;
            },
        ),
    );
}

// access it using the ServiceManager where you need it
$myService = $sm->get('myService');
```

Comment: plugin class is under controller\Plugin\  and is invokable by using return array ( 'controller_plugins' => array(
      'invokables' => array(
          'AclPlugin' => 'Auth\Controller\Plugin\AclPlugin',
      ),  
    ), ); but somehow I am getting error when i use $this->getController()->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default'); in plugin class error is Fatal error: Call to a member function getServiceLocator() on a non-object in /module/Auth/src/Auth/Controller/Plugin/AclPlugin.php

Comment: Can you please paste your controller plugin class? I do this exactly the same way and it works for me. Also, please state your ZF2 version (betaN/RCn/2.0.0).

Comment: version is zf2 stable relase 2.0.0. please see class in question above

Comment: How are you using/calling this class?

Comment: Oh -- ok, that's the problem. Controller plugins are designed to be used inside a controller. They implement a pluggable method pattern and can be invoked using `$this->pluginName()->doSomething` in the controller context. In thise case, the Controller plugin system takes care of instantiation and assigns the controller instance. However, you can implement the ServiceManagerAwareInterface in that class and inject the ServiceManager from the module before invoking the `checkAcl` method..

Comment: any example you can recommend?

Comment: I can recommend [this approach](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/ZF2-What-s-the-proper-way-to-register-global-MVC-plugins-td4265227.html). You need to read a little but I did it mostly this way and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

changed the above AclPlugin class as below

```
namespace Auth\Controller\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;
use Zend\EventManager\EventInterface as Event;
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Auth\Entity\User;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManagerAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
class AclPlugin extends AbstractPlugin implements ServiceManagerAwareInterface
{

   /*
    * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
    */
    protected $em;

    protected $sm;

    public function checkAcl($e)
    {

        $this->setServiceManager( $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager() );

        $auth = new AuthenticationService();
        if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
            $storage = $auth->getStorage()->read();            
            if (!empty($storage->role))
                $role = strtolower ( $storage->role );            
            else 
                $role = "guest";            
        } else {
            $role = "guest";            
        }
        $app = $e->getParam('application');
        $acl          = new \Auth\Acl\AclRules(); 

        $matches      = $e->getRouteMatch();
        $controller   = $matches->getParam('controller');
        $action       = $matches->getParam('action', 'index');

        $resource = strtolower( $controller );
        $permission = strtolower( $action );

        if (!$acl->hasResource($resource)) {
            throw new \Exception('Resource ' . $resource . ' not defined');
        }

        if ($acl->isAllowed($role, $resource, $permission)) {

            $query = $this->getEntityManager($e)->createQuery('SELECT u FROM Auth\Entity\User u');
            $resultIdentities = $query->execute();

            var_dump($resultIdentities);
            foreach ($resultIdentities as $r)
                echo $r->username;
            exit();


            return;

        } else {
            $matches->setParam('controller', 'Auth\Controller\User'); // redirect
            $matches->setParam('action', 'accessdenied');    

            return;
        }

    }



    public function getEntityManager() {

        if (null === $this->em) {
            $this->em = $this->sm->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');

        }
        return $this->em;
    }

    public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

   /**
    * Retrieve service manager instance
    *
    * @return ServiceManager
    */
    public function getServiceManager()
    {
        return $this->sm->getServiceLocator();
    }

    /**
    * Set service manager instance
    *
    * @param ServiceManager $locator
    * @return void
    */
    public function setServiceManager(ServiceManager $serviceManager)
    {
        $this->sm = $serviceManager;
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually getting ServiceManager in controller plugin is quite easy!

Just use: `$this->getController()->getServiceLocator()`

Example:

```
namespace Application\Controller\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;

class Translate extends AbstractPlugin 
{

    public function __invoke($message, $textDomain = 'default', $locale = null) 
    {
        /** @var \Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator $translator */
        $translator = $this->getController()->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');

        return $translator->translate($message, $textDomain, $locale);
    }
}
```