# creating own service with default doctrine2 connection in zf2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

i'm learning zf2 with doctrine2.

Doctrine2 entities is not good place for putting logic there, so i have to create something like services.

I created new catalog in src - Service, and i thought that i will create abstractService class, which will have by default access to doctrine2 entity manager, and other usefull stuff further.

But i'm not sure how to achieve it, i created constructor, where i should pass instance of object manager through injection, but i don't know how to do it. All found examples are for controllers.

Can somebody show me way ho to manage/organise it?

I didn't found any solutions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562538/zf2-creation-of-simple-service-and-access-it-through-viewhelper

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421565/zf2-doctrine2-getservicelocator-in-plugin-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the default doctrine entity manager from the service manager using eighter `doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default` or the alias `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager`.

```
$serviceLocator->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
```

Best practice for dependency injection in ZF2 is to use service factories which you register on the service manager. There is plenty of information about this available.

Anyway I'll explain the steps.

**Your service**

```
namespace MyNamespace
class MyService
{
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
}
```

**Factory**
Define the factory in your `module.php`

```
class Module
{
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'MyNamespace\MyService' => function($serviceLocator) {
                    return new MyService($serviceLocator->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
                }
            )
        );
    }
}
```

I have used a closure for the factory for this example, but it's recommended to use a dedicated factory class.

Now you can retrieve your fully composed service from the service manager.

```
$serviceManager->get('MyNamespace\MyService');
```

If you want to use this service in your controller you'll need to define a factory for this in the same way I did above. There's just one small difference, because all controllers are managed by a seperate pluginManager (a serviceManager dedicated to creating classes of a certain type). You can use the method `getControllerConfig` in your module.php to define factories on the controller plugin manager.

Add this to your module.php

```
public function getControllerConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'MyNamespace\Controller\MyController' => function($serviceLocator)
            {
                $rootLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
                $service = $rootLocator->get('MyNamespace\MyService');
                return new MyController($service);
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Hope this helps.